# How do you navigate to a user profile with Google uid without showing it in the url

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase, angular-ui-router, google-authentication

I was just wondering how to navigate to a users profile with their google uid in ui-router. I'm assuming that this is sensitive information that shouldn't be displayed but I'm not really too sure so I figured I would ask to make sure I'm doing things the right way.

The link I am using is:

```
<a ui-sref="timeline.profile({ userKey: post.userKey })" ui-sref-active="selected">{{post.userKey}}</a>
```

Where userKey is equal to the google uid. And then this is my state for the public profile.

```
.state('timeline.profile', {
     url: '/{userKey}',
     views: {
       'timeline-tab@tab': {
         templateUrl: 'timeline/templates/public-profile.html',
           controller: 'PublicProfileCtrl as publicProfileCtrl'
       }
     },
     resolve: {
     auth: function($state, Auth){
       return Auth.$requireAuth().catch(function(){
       });
     },
     publicProfile: function(Users, Auth, $stateParams) {
       return Auth.$requireAuth().then(function(authData) {
         return Users.getPublicProfile($stateParams.userKey).$loaded();
       });
     }
    }
  })
```

It works for grabbing the users profile and navigating to the template but the url contains the google uid. I was just wondering how to achieve the same result without showing the google uid if that is sensitive information that shouldn't be shown.

And I was also wondering if this was good practice to create two different profiles. A private profile where the user can access all of their information and then a public profile that just displays the information.

Comment: Not really clear what you're asking here. How to navigate to a user without knowing their UID (i.e. exposing it to the client at all) or how to simply avoid putting something in the URL and still show it in the browser (the possibilities here are pretty much limitless). Is it only the logged in user's uid or are we viewing other users' profiles? Why is putting it into the URl a problem?

Comment: Sorry I should have made my question a little clearer. I have access to the users google uid so I'm trying to create a path to veiw other users profiles. If the user is logged in then the url to their own profile is just /profile. But to access other users profiles I pass in their google uid (userkey) so the url shows up as timeline/google:1234********. So right now everyone can see the google uid in the url. The path works but I was just wondering if its bad that everyone can see the users google uid in the url. Thank you for the response.